# Device Id Access

Tags: android, mobile

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo `Android` e gostaria de usar o `Device ID` onde o aplicativo for executado para compor uma identificação.

É possível fazer acesso a essa informação?

A ideia é identificar o usuário do aplicativo por um campo composto pelo id do dispositivo (que acredito seja único) e por outra informação ainda em estudos.

Comment: Olá vtra, considere aceitar minha resposta se ela lhe foi útil. Se achar que ela está incompleta ou não te atende, faça os devidos comentários para que eu possa melhorá-la.

Answer (score 4):

Isso é possível:

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), ANDROID_ID);
```

Retirado originalmente [desta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id) pergunta.

[Documentação do Settings.Secure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID)